# Find the last non blank value of a column, but keep the rest blank in R

Tags: r

I have a dataframe as such,  I would like to change the column UR by keeping only the last non blank value of this column, leaving the rest of the cells blank.

| Date| GEO| AGE|UR
|:---- |:------:| -----:| -----:|
|  2019-01-01 | can| 15-24|
|  2019-01-01 | ont| 15-24|5.2
|  2019-02-01 | can| 15-24|6.4
|  2019-02-01 | ont| 15-24|
| ----| ----| ----|-----
| ----| ----| ----|-----
|  2021-01-01 | can| 15-24|
|  2021-01-01 | ont| 15-24|3.8
|  2021-02-01 | can| 15-24|12.3
|  2021-02-01 | ont| 15-24|
|  2020-03-01 | can| 15-24|
|  2020-03-01 | on| 15-24|
So my results should be

| Date| GEO| AGE|UR
|:---- |:------:| -----:| -----:|
|  2019-01-01 | can| 15-24|
|  2019-01-01 | ont| 15-24|
|  2019-02-01 | can| 15-24|
|  2019-02-01 | ont| 15-24|
| ----| ----| ----|
| ----| ----| ----|
|  2021-01-01 | can| 15-24|
|  2021-01-01 | ont| 15-24|3.8
|  2021-02-01 | can| 15-24|12.3
|  2021-02-01 | ont| 15-24|
|  2020-03-01 | can| 15-24|
|  2020-03-01 | on| 15-24|
So my results should be

my codes is wrong

```r
ur %>%
  group_by(GEO,SEX, AGE) %>%
  mutate(smaller = ifelse(!smaller==" ", row_number() == n(),
      smaller, " "))->ur  #create the last data point
```

Comment: you're working with an object, so rather than the chart above `dput(head(my_object))`, and paste the `structure(...)`, above as data at bottom.

Comment: which column is the `SEX` in the data

Answer (score 1):

Grouped by the 'GEO', 'AGE' (`SEX` was not showed in the example), find the `last` index of non-NA, create a condition with `!=` with `row_number()` and `replace` the values to `NA`

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
   group_by(GEO, AGE) %>%
   mutate(ind = replace(UR, row_number() != last(which(!is.na(UR))), NA)) %>%
   ungroup
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 6 × 5
  Date       GEO   AGE      UR   ind
  <chr>      <chr> <chr> <dbl> <dbl>
1 2019-01-01 can   15-24   9.3  NA  
2 2019-01-01 ont   15-24   5.2   5.2
3 2019-02-01 can   15-24   6.4  NA  
4 2019-02-01 ont   15-24  NA    NA  
5 2019-03-01 can   15-24  10.2  10.2
6 2019-03-01 ont   15-24  NA    NA
```

---

Or using `case_when`

```
df1 %>% 
  group_by(GEO, AGE) %>%
  mutate(UR = case_when(row_number() == last(which(!is.na(UR))) ~ UR)) %>%
  ungroup
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(Date = c("2019-01-01", "2019-01-01", "2019-02-01", 
"2019-02-01", "2019-03-01", "2019-03-01"), GEO = c("can", "ont", 
"can", "ont", "can", "ont"), AGE = c("15-24", "15-24", "15-24", 
"15-24", "15-24", "15-24"), UR = c(9.3, 5.2, 6.4, NA, 10.2, NA
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```

Comment: this works, but the problem is that I need to keep the UR that is in decending order from the last date.  i.e. the datframe runs all the way to 2021-03-01, so I want to look from the last date in reverse order and keep only the latest non blank cells